# Puppeteer throws Target closed error on AWS lambda locally

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium

I want to convert html string to pdf file. I use NodeJS on AWS lambda and Puppeteer for that. Here is the logic of service:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");

async generatePdf(html = ''): Promise<Buffer> {    
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
            headless: true,
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
            args: [
              ...chromium.args,
              '--no-sandbox',
              '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
              '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
              '--single-process',
              '--headless',
              '--disable-gpu',
              '--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess',
              '--no-zygote',
            ],
            pipe: true
        });

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

        const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            format: 'a4',
            margin: { top: 24, bottom: 50, left: 24, right: 24 },
            footerTemplate: (`
              <div style="display: table-footer-group; position: fixed; font-family: 'Open Sans', Verdana, Helvetica,  sans-serif; font-size: 8px; width: 545px; text-align:right; padding: 0 20px;">
                  <div>Page <span class="pageNumber"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></div>
              </div>
            `)
        });
        await page.close();
        await browser.close();

        return pdfBuffer;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

I launch my lambdas inside Docker container, here is my Docker file:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16 as builder
WORKDIR /var/task/
COPY package.json  ./
COPY package-lock.json  ./
COPY locales ./locales
RUN npm install

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:16
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
ADD ./ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY --from=builder /var/task/ /
ENTRYPOINT [ "/lambda-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Here is my template.yaml file:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  Todo

Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"

Parameters:
  NodeEnv:
    Type: String
    Default: "default"
  AwsRegion:
    Type: String
    Default: "default"
  AppEnv:
    Type: String
    Default: "default"
  SGid:
    Type: String
    Default: "default"
  SubnetIds:
    Type: List<String>
    Default: "default"

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs16.x
    MemorySize: 2024
    Timeout: 100
    Environment:
      Variables:
        NODE_ENV: !Ref NodeEnv
    VpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SGid
      SubnetIds: !Ref SubnetIds

Resources:
  ChromiumLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      Description: Chromium with Node.js integration for AWS Lambda
      ContentUri: layers/chromium
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - &nodejsRuntime nodejs16.x
      CompatibleArchitectures:
        - &chromiumArch x86_64
      RetentionPolicy: Delete
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: *nodejsRuntime
      BuildArchitecture: *chromiumArch

  ReportFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Metadata:
    Properties:
      Architectures:
        - *chromiumArch
      Layers:
        - !Ref ChromiumLayer
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 2024
      Handler: report/src/main.handler
      CodeUri: dist/apps
      Description:
      Events:
        Report:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /report
            Method: ANY
```

I use the following versions of software:

- puppeteer-core 19.8.0
- chromium 112
- Docker desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
- Mac OS 14.2.1 on M1 Silicon

About 90% of requests fail with error:

```
[Nest] 26  - 12/25/2023, 1:18:55 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Target closed
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Target closed
    at new Callback (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:61:35)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:106:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:216:26)
    at CDPSessionImpl.send (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:419:78)
    at CDPPage.createPDFStream (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:741:88)
    at CDPPage.pdf (/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:767:37)
    at FilesService.generatePdf (/var/task/files/src/files.service.js:225:42)
```

Sometimes lambda returns pdf file, but it is corrupted, I can't open it, the system says: failed to load PDF document. If I try to open it via **cat** command, I see in my terminal:
[image: file 1]
[image: file 2]

I tried to play with puppeteer options, nothing helped. Any help is appreciated.